# On changing the orientation,Media stops playing and fires media failed event in Metro style application(Windows 8)

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

This problem is in w8 windows metro style app.I am using c# as my programming language.
I have one media element added in a page and using that media element i play a media file  hosted in my localhost. After playing the media when i change the orientation of the simulator,I get media failed event and media stops playing.

How to solve this problem?
is this a bug from windows side?

Comment: did u check your application on Tablet?

Comment: on simulator this is an issue or not work. but when u check media element on tablet so it will work fine.

Comment: The tablet which i have does not support orientation change event.When i change the orientation in the device it does not change anything. Basically i have installed windows 8 on windows 7 Tablet.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post should answer your question: [Visual Studio 2012's simulator causes video to stop playback when orientation is changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mediasdkstuff/archive/2012/08/31/visual-studio-2012-s-simulator-causes-video-to-stop-playback-when-orientation-is-changed.aspx)

> This is actually a known issue in the simulator. Unfortunately I don't
>   when or if this is going to be fixed. The team is aware of the problem
>   though so I expect that we will see a fix sometime in the future I
>   just can't say when. The good news is that this problem doesn't affect
>   a slate / tablet / surface device.